# Ошибка в фильтрации товаров в ocStore 3.0.3.7

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, из за чего начало выдавать ошибку в фильтре??

Магазин на платформе ocStore 3.0.3.7

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error: Invalid use of group function<br />Error No: 1111<br />SELECT p.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM oc_review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT price FROM oc_product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '2' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM oc_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '2' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, coalesce((SELECT price FROM oc_product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '2' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' O in /home/sldybopt/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 41
```

Ссылка на категорию, где есть фильтр
https://bermudys.com/all/caviar/sturgeon-caviar/beluga-hybrid

Comment: Покажите проблемный запрос полностью - в сообщении об ошибке он обрезан.

Comment: Скрин на ошибку https://prnt.sc/GH-DSeXiZ2ju